# Can I make media server using RTSP, MPEG2-TS over RTP?

Tags: rtsp, mpeg2-ts

Using RTSP Protocol, Can I send MPEG2-TS RTP Packet?

In VLC Player, I can use MPEG-2 TS over RTP. 
But It is only supporting RTP, not using RTSP
(requesting url => rtp://{server ip}:{port}/{path})

Answer (score 0):

in the tutorial, https://support.spinetix.com/wiki/Tutorial:Streaming_using_VLC#Transcode_into_MPEG_TS_and_stream_over_RTP.2FTS

you should use rtsp as your source